# Gparted shows incorrect used space

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, gparted

I want to clone my system over to a 16GB SSD, but can't seem to shrink the partition in Gparted to fit. I've cleared the trash and everything, and Nautilus seems to show only 8GB used. However, when I try to shrink the partition in gparted from a live USB, it shows 19GB used, which won't fit on the SSD. It's strange, because the actual files only take up 8GB. I tried running "sudo du -h /" and it showed 8GB total when the command finished.

How do I get rid of this nonexistent data so that I can shrink my partition down to 16GB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by shrinking to 25GB first, then it shows the correct space remaining.